# jQuery based text search/filter works, but not for all fields

Tags: jquery

[Live example](http://viewhighlights.herokuapp.com/)

I currently have a jQuery based search that I'm using to filter cards (divs), but it currently works only for text inside the details field. I'd like it to work for the other fields, e.g. title/tags/source, as well but I'm not sure how to do so. The jQuery script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.highlight').hide();
    $('.highlight:contains("'+value+'")').show();
  });
```

And each card in HTML is

```
<div class="highlight">
  <summary>
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title"><%=h.title%>,</span>
      <span class="comment"><%=h.comment%></span>
      <p class="source">
        <a href="<%-h.link%>"><%=h.source%></a>
        <span class="date"><%=h.date%></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <% h.tags.forEach((t)=>{%>
          <% if (t) { %>
            <span class="tag"><%=t%></span>
          <% } %>
        <%})%>
      </p>
    </div>
    <details>
      <% h.content.forEach((d)=>{%>
          <p><%=d%></p>
      <%})%>
    </details>
  </summary>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like case sensitive and case insensitive text matching problem.
Try this, please check if there is any syntax error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.expr[':'].containsIgnoreCase = function (n, i, m) {
        return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
   $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
       var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       $('.highlight').hide();
       $('.highlight:containsIgnoreCase("'+value+'")').show();
   });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, I take back my initial comment, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    console.log('here')
    var value = $(this).val();//.toLowerCase();

    $('.highlight').hide();
    $('.highlight :contains('+value+')').parents('.highlight').show();


  });
```

you are converting search value to lowerCase but this will not match with your text. If you want to do not case sensitive you have to convert your text to lower case in search time too. not only the input value

Comment: This works for the tags, but still not for source or title